# rotation matrix - why am I thinking this wrong?

Tags: vectors, rotation

The rotation given in [Question 1 part ii)](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:90rNivmw2zkJ%3aoyc.yale.edu/sites/default/files/problem_set_4_solutions_0.pdf%20&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjKcH-24ACiFjxemz3kjJ9zZj1Qs2cvJozFmdWlW8zUsGpDKk7mvIgMp8G-8mfEKObhOWGK14S_fTF4IAH8wS-IY8B_iDAzHR5c2TFwypapEcHYwBlOWzwErf1543HtxX5sC2Ol&sig=AHIEtbQeTqMeHrAAoFnd5VtfFt5IuEfC-w) doesn't match with this wikipedia link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix.

$$ \begin{array}{lcl}
x' &=& x \cos\theta - y \sin\theta \\
y' &=& x \sin\theta + y \cos\theta
\end{array}$$
What's the difference? Why are the two answers different? (I don't think it's a mistake on the previous link.)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/I24ts.png

http://i.stack.imgur.com/NskeQ.png

Comment: You shouldn't post equations as images. This site supports [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) for rendering LaTeX equations (here's a [short guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf), google for much more info). I'll fix this for you for now.

Answer (score 5):

You need to be careful to make the distinction between rotating the vector $\mathbf A$ counterclockwise in which case you would have
$$
  A_x' = A_x\cos\theta - A_y\sin\theta, \qquad A_y' = A_x\sin\theta + A_y\cos\theta
$$
and rotating the basis vectors counterclockwise and then finding the components of $\mathbf A$ in the resulting basis which results in the above expressions with the replacement $\theta\to-\theta$.  To see what I mean, draw a vector $\mathbf A$ in the plane, then imagine (a) rotating the vector counterclockwise and then calculating the resulting components (b) rotating the basis vectors counterclockwise while keeping $\mathbf A$ fixed and then computing the components of $\mathbf A$ in the rotated basis.

Another way of seeing this is that for any rotation $R(\theta)$ counterclockwise by $\theta$ the situation (a) corresponds to (using the summation convention)
$$
  A_i' = R(\theta)_{ij} A_j
$$
while situation (b) corresponds to
$$
  A_i' = \mathbf A\cdot (R(\theta)\mathbf{e}_i) = A_j(R(\theta) \mathbf e_i)_j = A_jR(\theta)_{jk}\delta_{ik} = A_jR(\theta)_{ji} =  R(-\theta)_{ij} A_j
$$
where the last equality follows from the fact that $R^{-1} = R^t$ for rotations.  The situations differ by the replacement $\theta\to-\theta$ as claimed.

Comment: Just adding, that people use to name this two operations as passive (applying the rotation, or redefining, the coordinates) and active (as physically moving the system in space).